# OSGi - What does system.bundle mean?

Tags: java, osgi, jboss7.x, apache-felix

I am new to OSGi. I'm using Apache felix in Jboss AS 7.1 for OSGi container. On accessing 'localhost:8090/system/console' I can find the list of bundles that are installed. When I check a bundle's import packages, I can find few are imported from system.bundle.

*Imported Packages   javax.activation,version=0.0.0 from **system.bundle** (0)*

My questions are, what does **system.bundle** mean? Where is it loaded from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The system bundle is the OSGi framework itself. So typically felix or equinox.
It is special as it is the only bundle that is not loaded by the framework. It also has the duty to export some of the java packages like the javax ones for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!